# Purchase request from production order

Tags: tryton

I've just started testing Tryton ERP with regards to production planning, and I don't get automatic procurement working;

I define "Part A" with a vendor and price.
I then define "Product B" with a BoM of 1 * Part A.
Now when I create a production order, I'd expect a purchase request for Part A at some point, but I don't.

I tried installing the "Sale Supply" module, but that only seem to work on actual sales orders. I want to create production orders without actual sales yet.

Is this possible? It seems like a really easy thing to do...

Comment: Have you executed the create purchase request wizard?

Comment: @pokoli Ah, there is a scheduler! When I manually changed it to run every 5 minutes I got my purchase draft! Thanks!

Comment: Yes, by default it runs daily, as it will earase the draft purchase request and recreate them.